# Clone wp-admin/users.php (Users Admin Page)

Tags: custom-post-types, users, user-roles, table, wp-list-table

I have created a new page in admin. I need to show all the users in this page(like Users admin page).

The reason for this is because i want to show certain custom user roles only on this page.

I tried using `WP_List_Table` but no luck in figuring out on how to implement.

This is the function i have, i need to put the code inside here.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'cypolicy_users_admin_menu' );

function cypolicy_users_admin_page_contents() 
{
echo "<h1>" . esc_html_e( 'CyPolicy Users', 'cypolicy-users-plugin-textdomain' ) . "</h1>";


}
```

Can someone kindly guide me.

Comment: have you considered instead modifying the admin menu to lead to the dedicated role listing pages that already exist? e.g. `/wp-admin/users.php?role=editor` wouldn't adding that as a menu in the sidebar under users also solve the problem this is trying to resolve? `WP_List_Table` and brand new pages aren't necessary

Comment: @TomJNowell yes i did, but the client want a seperate page. Please see my menu structure here. This is how he wants https://snipboard.io/5Bg9w4.jpg

Comment: I don't see why that isn't possible, just add it as a menu instead of a sub-menu, nothing prevents you from adding new menu pages in the admin menu, whether they lead to custom pages, or URLs that already exist, or even google.com ( https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/ )

Comment: e.g. something similar to this will add a top level nav menu item called Google visible to editors: `add_menu_page( 'Google', 'Google', 'edit_posts', 'https://google.com', '', 'dashicons-admin-home', 1);`, nothing stops you doing this with the role filters, and it's 1000x easier than what you're trying to do (and unlike your proposed solution it's compatible with plugins etc)

Comment: @TomJNowell the point here is that i need a seperate page. I dont need menu now. I have already created a blank page. I want to show the list of user there.

Comment: I see, that's unfortunate, the end result would be the same but it would take much more work, and have plugin compatibility issues, as well as needing to rebuild a lot of the users page. My comment was just pointing out that you can save yourself a week of developer time by adding a direct link to the page that already exists. That would allow you to instead focus on hiding the roles menu and changing the pages title which is much much easier/faster to do. Creating a whole new page is unnecessary and a lot of work

Comment: @TomJNowell i completely agree with you. But my client is beyond logic. He needs it in this way so that each module looks whole.

Comment: That doesn't mean it has to be built that way, the client is only concerned with the end result. To reuse a phrase, they don't need to know how the sausage is made. If they're insistent on a specific technical implementation you can remind them that one option will take minutes, the other will take days, remind them how much they're being billed per day and any resistance should fade away :)

Comment: For reference the Users title at the top is assigned via `__( 'Users' )` so it can be changed using localisation filters to something else based on the URL parameters, and you can get rid of the menu of role filters at the top several ways but the easiest is this CSS rule `.users-php .subsubsub { display: none; }`. Also keep in mind that people using screen readers or assistance will not be able to tell the different "Users" menus apart in the design you linked to